# What are useful introductory books & websites for AD&D 2E players?

Tags: adnd-2e

The mechanics of Advanced D&D 2E are rather different from editions 3.5-5. What are useful books & websites for players to learn AD&D 2E?

Answer (score 3):

### Read the core books

Like with every edition of the game, the rules are in the Player's Handbook and the Dungeon Master's Guide (and in regard to monsters, in the Monstrous Manual, which was the name of the Monster Handbook at the time).

Read those, in particular the PHB. This will give you a better understanding of the rules mechanics of D&D 2e than any other book you could read.